# How to retrieve data from Firebase using AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, firebase, aws-lambda

Can someone help me with connecting my Firebase with AWS Lambda? I really have no idea how to do it. The purpose of our application is for it to retrieve recipes (recipe name, ingredients, procedures, etc.) stored from our Firebase and let Amazon Alexa read it. The application should be able to search for a certain recipe and if the user already chose a recipe, Alexa would read the procedures of the recipe. I really have no idea how to do this, please help. Thank you.

Comment: You could probably use REST API endpoints, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start

Comment: Thank you Renaud! I'll try to read this and see what I can do. I'll get back to you when I still can't figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Firebase Admin](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup). You can Deploy using Node/JAVA/Python/GO

Firebase Admin node sample

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var comfun = require('./commonfunctions');
var fs = require('fs');
var admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
var serviceAccount = require("path to credential file");
router.post('/signup', function (req, res, next) {
    var userdet = (req.body);
    var db = admin.firestore();
    var docRef = db.collection('users').doc(userdet.uid);
    var setAda = docRef.set({
        userdet
    }).then(() => {
        res.statusCode=200;
        res.json({
            "status": "success",
            "message": "saved succesfully"
        })
    }).catch((err) => {
        res.statusCode=500;
        res.json({
            "status": "failure",
            "message": err
        })
    });
});
```

Hope this is useful!

Comment: I already tried doing it but I still can't figure out what function to call to get the data in firebase. Can you provide a sample code?